# Allocation using temp, why is this way better?

Tags: objective-c

```
//.h file
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *data;

//.m file
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.data = temp;
[temp release];
```

Why is this way (using temporary variable) is better than this

```
self.data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second way leaks the newly-created dictionary.  You could use:

```
self.data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

And it would be as safe as your first example.

*Edited to match OP's update to the question.*

Comment: This code will be added to "init" method and I don't have nothing put in when I create the object but I am going to add values later..

Comment: @LCYSoft, that's not going to work. You can't add *any* objects to an `NSDictionary` once it's been created.  Maybe you want `NSMutableDictionary`?

Comment: It's an immutable dictionary. You *can't* add values later. If you want to add values later, use NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: I deleted my answer and upvoted this one, since it's basically identical, and Carl answered first.